# $[F(\alpha, \beta): F]=mn$ if $m,n$ are coprime

Tags: abstract-algebra, field-theory, extension-field

If $K$ is a field extension of $F$ and $\alpha, \beta\in K$, with $\alpha, \beta$ algebraic over $F$ and $\deg(\alpha)=m$, $\deg(\beta)=n$, such that $m,n$ are coprime, then $[F(\alpha,\beta):F]=mn$.

I don't actually know what it means to say that $\deg(\alpha)=m$. Does this mean that the degree of the minimal polynomial whose root is $\alpha$ is $m$? If so then I'm not sure how to proceed.

Would appreciate some clarification.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Product of degree of two field extensions of prime degree](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1612311/product-of-degree-of-two-field-extensions-of-prime-degree). Your case is a bit more general but the same proof applies (see the comments on the answer).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are correct that $n$ and $m$ are the degrees of the irreducible polynomial.

To see the theorem, notice that $\{\alpha^r\beta^s\}$ forms a basis of $F(\alpha,\beta)$ if and only if $F(\alpha)\cap F(\beta)=F$. Thus $[F(\alpha, \beta):F]=nm$ if the intersection contains only the ground field.

Let $\gamma\in F(\alpha)\cap F(\beta)$. Then $F(\gamma)\subseteq F(\alpha)\cap F(\beta)$, and therefore $\deg(\gamma)\mid \deg(\alpha),\deg(\beta)$. Since $n$ and $m$ are coprime, this implies $\deg(\gamma)=1$, so $\gamma\in F$.

Comment: Thanks. I'm not quite sure how to determine that $\{\alpha^r\beta^s \}$ forms a basis for $F(\alpha, \beta)$ if and only if $F(\alpha)\cap F(\beta)=F$. Can you please explain?

Comment: @sequence it clearly spans the set, so we need only show for the first direction that it is linearly independent. If there is an element in the intersection, then it is a linear combination of $\{\alpha^r\}$ and of $\{\beta^s\}$. Take the difference as the linear combination, so that it isn't a basis.

Answer (score 3):

Hint: $F(\alpha, \beta) \supset F(\alpha) \supset F$ and $F(\alpha, \beta) \supset F(\beta) \supset F$ are two towers of finite extensions.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, $\deg(\alpha) = m$ means that the minimum polynomial of $\alpha$ has degree $m$. It is equivalent to $[F(\alpha):F] = m$.

To proceed, use the fact that in a tower of (algebraic) extensions $F \subseteq K \subseteq L$, $[L:F] = [L:K] [K:F]$.

Answer (score 1):

We know $F(\alpha,\beta)\supseteq F(\alpha)\supseteq F$ and $F(\alpha,\beta)\supseteq F(\beta)\supseteq F$. So, We can say the following about degrees
$$[F(\alpha,\beta):F] = [F(\alpha,\beta):F(\alpha)][F(\alpha):F] = [F(\alpha,\beta):F(\alpha)]\cdot m$$
$$[F(\alpha,\beta):F] = [F(\alpha,\beta):F(\beta)][F(\beta):F] = [F(\alpha,\beta):F(\beta)]\cdot n$$
Now, we know that $[F(\alpha,\beta):F] \le mn$ (As the basis of $F(\alpha,\beta)$ can have at most $mn$ distinct elements i.e. {$\alpha^r.\beta^s:0\le r\le m-1,0\le s\le n-1 $}).
But we see $[F(\alpha,\beta):F]$ is a common multiple of $m$ and $n$. Since, they are relatively prime $lcm(m,n) = mn$. Thus, $[F(\alpha,\beta):F] = mn$.