# Degree of field extension using Tower Law

Tags: abstract-algebra, field-theory, extension-field, minimal-polynomials

Let $L:K$ be a field extension and $a,b \in L$. Suppose $[K(a):K]=m$ and $[K(b):K]=n$

why is it that $[K(a,b):K]=mn$?

I’ve tried to solve this using the tower Law but to use this I need to show $[K(a,b):K(a)]=m$.

How is this certainly the case? Must the minimal polynomial of $b$ over $K$ and $K(a)$ necessarily be the same?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a counterexample. Let $L=\mathbb{Q}(2^{1/4})$ and $K=\mathbb{Q}$. Then, if we $a=2^{1/2}$ and $b=2^{1/4}$ (and both belongs to $L$), then
$$[\mathbb{Q}(2^{1/4}): \mathbb{Q}]=4,\qquad [\mathbb{Q}(2^{1/2}): \mathbb{Q}]=2$$
but 
$$[\mathbb{Q}(2^{1/4}, 2^{1/2}): \mathbb{Q}]=[\mathbb{Q}(2^{1/4}): \mathbb{Q}] =4 \neq 2\cdot 4 =8.$$
However, your statement holds when $m$ and $n$ are coprimes. You can see the proof here:

[Product of degree of two field extensions of prime degree](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1612311/product-of-degree-of-two-field-extensions-of-prime-degree)

Comment: Hi. In that answer it says the minimal polynomial over $\mathbb{Q}$ is the same as the minimal polynomial over the field $\mathbb{Q}(\beta)$. Why is this the case, surely the minimal polynomial over $\mathbb{Q}$ could no longer be irreducible in the larger field?

Comment: I think I made a mistake.

Comment: I’m not sure you can say mn divides the degree of $\mathbb{Q}(a,b)$ like at the start of his argument when we don’t know a and b are distinct primes.

Comment: Are you referring to the link I added?

Comment: Yessssssssssssss

Comment: Observe that $[\mathbb{Q}(a):\mathbb{Q}]$ and $[\mathbb{Q}(b):\mathbb{Q}]$ divide $[\mathbb{Q}(a,b):\mathbb{Q}]$ (this is always true, no matter if they are prime or not). You know that $[\mathbb{Q}(a):\mathbb{Q}]$ and $[\mathbb{Q}(b):\mathbb{Q}]$ divide $[\mathbb{Q}(a,b):\mathbb{Q}]$ (this is always true, no matter if they are prime or not). Now, if they are coprime, $[\mathbb{Q}(a):\mathbb{Q}]\cdot[\mathbb{Q}(b):\mathbb{Q}]$ divides $[\mathbb{Q}(a,b):\mathbb{Q}]$.